# Is it possible to integrate doodle (doodle.com) with a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, web-applications

I'm seeing doodle doesn't have maintained ruby-client to access the API.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. doodle.com provides a REST API http://www.doodle.com/about/APIs.html

You can consume this REST web service in your ruby program. You can check rest-client for consuming in your ruby/rails program. https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client

Comment: the first link is broken right now, is there any up to date info on this?